# Problema con inserción en MySQL WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un programa con PHP, SQL y usando como SGBD MySQL. El caso es que quiero realizar inserciones cuando el id=0. El código es este:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `logs_articulos_api_csv` (`fecha_inicio_ejecucion`) VALUES ('$fecha_comienzo_programa') WHERE `id`=$id";
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id`=0' at line 1
```

Si imprimo la sentencia SQL que me da error es ésta:

```
INSERT INTO `logs_articulos_api_csv` (`fecha_inicio_ejecucion`) VALUES ('19/11/2020') WHERE `id`=0
```

Y si la ejecuto en MySQL me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Se encontraron 2 errores durante el análisis.

Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "WHERE" at position 86)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "WHERE" at position 86)
```

Sin embargo, yo no veo fallo alguna en la sentencia de inserción. A ver si vosotros lo veis. Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he investigado y he visto que no se pueden poner cláusulas `WHERE` en una sentencia `INSERT INTO`. He optado por la siguiente solución:

```
$sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `fecha_inicio_ejecucion`='$fecha_inicio_ejecucion' WHERE `id`=$id";
```

Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Se puede, si usas una sub-consulta para tomar los datos que quieres insertar, es decir, la sub-consulta sería una consulta `SELECT` normal con su cláusula `WHERE` dentro. Lo que no me queda claro es si aplique para este caso, si puedes hacerlo con un `UPDATE` es porque se trata de datos que ya existen en la tabla, y eso no tiene nada que ver con un `INSERT`

Comment: Son registros dónde existe ya un ```id``` pero el resto de campos están a NULL.

Comment: Pues lo dicho, si los registros existen el `INSERT` no tiene ningún sentido, porque el mismo es para crear registros nuevos mientras que el `UPDATE` es para actualizar registros que ya existen. El asunto en sí no es que no se puede usar un `WHERE` en un `INSERT`, porque sí se puede, es más bien un error de enfoque.

Comment: Gracias por el feedback :)

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que te refieres a un insert .... select. Pero no es lo que está haciendo esta persona. La sintaxis para un insert select es insert into table (valor, valor.....) select XXXXXX from YYYY where ZZZZ

Comment: Si @RaulLuna, a eso me refiero. En todo caso OP necesitaba un UPDATE para este caso, no un INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Las clausulas where no se pueden poner en una sentencia de inserción. Sí se pueden poner en una sentencia update.

Comment: Las cláusulas `WHERE` sí pueden ponerse en una consulta de inserción (por ejemplo cuando se una una sub-consulta `SELECT` para tomar los datos a insertar). El error en esta pregunta es más bien de enfoque, realmente lo que OP necesita es un `UPDATE` porque los datos ya existen. Si él quisiera insertar datos nuevos desde cualquier tabla, podría usar sin problema un `INSERT` con `WHERE` en una sub-consulta.